# Can only upload certain programs to standalone Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, uploading

I can't upload a program that uses `digitalRead`, `analogRead`, and `Serial.print` on my standalone Arduino, because I get this error:

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xbf
```

However, I have no trouble uploading the blink program to it, which only uses `digitalWrite`, so it has to do something with the methods mentioned at the start of this post.

You can see the diagram below.

[image: diagram]

Comment: I added a connection between digital pin 9 and ground with an led

Comment: I uploaded the blink program, changed the dgital pin to 9 in the program, uploaded it and connected an led from digital pin 9 to ground. Then I can see the led is blinking every 1 second.

Comment: change the blink rate to 1/2 second

Comment: It can do that. Now it turns on/off every 500 ms.

Comment: ok, this is pretty weird. ... i originally thought that maybe you missed the download fail with the blink program, and the Arduino already had a blink program loaded. ... i have to think on this one

Comment: Please post (edit your question) the code that does not upload.

Comment: I do not see any decoupling capacitors between Vcc and AVcc and ground, which are **absolutely required**.

Comment: Also, remove the Aref connection to 5V. Aref should only have a 0.1uF cap to Gnd.
Won't affect programming, but could damage the internal ADC mux or other ADC circuits.